# aws sns using spring cloud aws not able to subscripe

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Hi I am trying to get the aws sns message in my spring endpoint code. I am making use of spring cloud aws. I have set up the configuration with my access and secret key. yet the message is struck in pending subscription.my controller class is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sns/receive")
public class SnsEndpointController1 {

@NotificationMessageMapping
public void receiveNotification(@NotificationMessage String message, @NotificationSubject String subject) {
    // ...
}

@NotificationSubscriptionMapping
public void confirmSubscription(NotificationStatus notificationStatus) {
    notificationStatus.confirmSubscription();
}
}
```

my xml file is:

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
       <ref bean="notificationResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven> 
<aws-messaging:notification-argument-resolver id="notificationResolver" />   
     <aws-context:context-credentials>
              <aws-context:instance-profile-credentials/>
              <aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="....."
                                              secret-key="....."/>
     </aws-context:context-credentials>
     <aws-context:context-region region="...."/>
</beans>
```

Please let me know what I am missing.